# how do i store android constants in a strings.xml file?

Tags: android, xml, configuration

I want to use something like this :

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="@string/textview_gravity" >
```

then in my strings.xml

have something like this:

```
<string name="textview_gravity" >bottom|right</string>
```

any ideas?  is this even possible?

Comment: Change gravity in yur code accordingly.  In xml I dont think its possible.

Answer (score 4):

no it is not possible. You should use `styles.xml` for this sort of things

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe you can use string constants that way in android. I believe you can only use string constants stored in an attribute field that expects a string field like:

```
        android:text="@string/some_string"
```